# Any way to *rewrite* example.com/blog/ URL to blog.otherdomain.com?

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have a Wordpress blog hosted on one server:
http://blog.example2.com/

And another site on a separate server:
http://www.example.com

Is it possible to get the blog to be served at the following URL?:
http://www.example.com/blog/

If so, I'd love to know how.  I messed around with mod-rewrite, but it looks like it will only redirect (not rewrite) to another URL, in this case.

For those interested: I realize I could install the blog on the same server, but I'd rather keep things decoupled for now.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use mod_proxy:

```
ProxyPass /blog http://blog.example2.com/
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.example2.com/
```

This'll need to be in server/vhost config. Otherwise, you can use it along with mod_rewrite in an htaccess file (in your document root):

```
RewriteRule ^/?blog/(.*)$ http://blog.example2.com/$1 [L,P]
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.example2.com/
```

If you're using cookies in your blog, you'll need to make sure to correct the paths/domains.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  The first line is working great when I got to example.com/blog.  The second line is causing an error in .htaccess.  Will be checking into this a little more.